# Change the color of the text in Toolbar menu

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I was spending some hours trying to change the color of the text in the menu in the toolbar.

The example. I have this toolbar:

[image]

I can change the color of the arrow and the tree dots with

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
```

I change the colors of the toolbar with:

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>

  <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar (with the
       battery, clock, etc). -->
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>

   <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for
        colorControlActivated which is used to tint widgets. -->
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
```

And the popupmenu defining a theme for the app:popuptheme atribute of the toolbar, but I cant change the color of the action menu with the text "Example". How can I do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I am not late to answer this.

Set

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/YourColor</item>
```

in your styles.xml to change menu item text color.

I hope this help.